# Compiler error with 'static const std::wstring DELETE;'

Tags: c++, static, constants, c++builder, vcl

I started a new VCL application under C++Builder, and I observe something bizarre.

When I declare a `const` member named `DELETE` as `std::string`, I get an error.

Here is the `.h` file:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef Communication_ButtonTagH
#define Communication_ButtonTagH    
#include <string>
namespace OverB::Communication
{
    class ButtonTag
    {
    public:
       static const  std::wstring  DELETE;
    };
}
#endif
```

And here is the `.cpp` file:

```
#include "Communication_ButtonTag.h"
namespace OverB::Communication
{
     const  std::wstring   ButtonTag::DELETE  = L"DELETE";
}
```

Changing only the name of the `const`, the application builds correctly.

I am using C++Builder 11.1 Alexandria, and Windows 11.

Here is the list of errors:

```
[C++ Error] Communication_ButtonTag.h(13, 32):  expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
[C++ Error] Communication_ButtonTag.h(13, 32):  expected ')'
[C++ Error] Communication_ButtonTag.h(13, 32):  to match this '('
[C++ Error] Communication_ButtonTag.cpp(5, 35):  expected unqualified-id
```

Can anyone explain what is happening exactly?

Comment: Can it be that DELETE is a macro?

Comment: There is probably some non-standard macro named DELETE defined somewhere. It is hard to tell where. Check your project settings. The error is not reproducible in other environments.

Comment: I found it in mapiwin.h and winnt.h. thank you very mush.

Comment: Let that be a lesson - don't use all upper-case identifiers unless they're macros.  It's an old convention that's followed just for this reason.

Comment: @MarkRansom It is not just all-uppercase identifiers that are affected by this issue, though. Microsoft also uses `#define` statements for `TCHAR`-based types and functions, too, which causes all kinds of problems for the VCL (`SetPort()` is a common example, as it interfers with several known component `Port` properties that have setters named `SetPort()`).

Comment: @RemyLebeau I can't tell you how many times I've been tripped up by those Microsoft macros.  I can't remember which causes me the most trouble, maybe `SetText`.  All to solve a problem that nobody's had for 30 years, converting narrow text code to wide text.

Comment: @MarkRansom That issue is not about *converting text between* narrow and wide. It is about *compiling text as either* narrow or wide. But I'd love to see the Win32 API updated to recognize C++ properly (namespaced [even if `using namespace ...` is used], overloaded function wrappers for legacy `A`/`W` functions, typed constants, etc), and use those old macros only when compiling for C.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you missed the word "code" in there.  The macros were a way to convert those API functions and structs without having to do a mass search and replace, since the "A" versions didn't exist originally.  And now we pay forever for a solution to a very short-term problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VCL is built on top of the Win32 API, which has a `DELETE` **preprocessor macro** defined in `winnt.h`:

```
#define DELETE                           (0x00010000L)
```

The preprocessor is run first, and it performs text replacements of defined macros before the compiler is run. Thus, after the preprocessor has processed your code and made its replacements, the compiler will see the following *invalid* code, which is why it errors:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef Communication_ButtonTagH
#define Communication_ButtonTagH    
#include <string>
namespace OverB::Communication
{
    class ButtonTag
    {
    public:
       static const  std::wstring  (0x00010000L);
    };
}
#endif
```

```
#include "Communication_ButtonTag.h"
namespace OverB::Communication
{
     const  std::wstring   ButtonTag::(0x00010000L)  = L"DELETE";
}
```

In short, don't declare your own variables and identifiers that happen to match the names of Win32 API macros.  The Win32 API is primarily a C library, not a C++ library.  It doesn't use properly typed constants, or respect namespaces, etc.  Common C++ best practices go out the window when dealing with the Win32 SDK.